# Визуализировать связи данных между компонентами таблиц на React JS

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Я визуализирую данные двух таблиц:

```
const json ={
  "tables": [
    {
      "tableName": "One",
      "coordinates": {
        "x": "100",
        "y": "100"
      },
      "columns": [
        {"name": "smthLike",
            "type": "string",
            "typeFormat": "",
            "example": "",
            "descriptor": ""},
        {"name": "@MainColumn",
            "type": "integer",
            "typeFormat": "int64",
            "example": "",
            "descriptor": "codePlatform"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "tableName": "Two",
      "coordinates": {
        "x": "200",
        "y": "200"
      },
      "columns": [
        {"name": "codePlatform",
            "type": "string",
            "typeFormat": "",
            "example": "",
            "descriptor": ""},
        {"name": "namePlatform",
            "type": "string",
            "typeFormat": "",
            "example": "",
            "descriptor": ""}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
введите сюда код
```

В работе я использую код библиотеки react-xarrows, Example 4: https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/Eliav2/react-xarrows/tree/master/examples?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

У таблиц есть ключи name descriptor. Если дескриптор совпадает с именем (codePlatform в данном случае), то стрелка связи данных должна тянуться от поля с codePlatform к тому полю, у которого является дескриптором (@MainColumn).

Я пыталась прописать такое условие, но пока не выходит. Чтобы отрисовать стрелку, нужно задать ей точку начала и точку конца. Подскажите, как можно прописать такое условие в компонент поля Column?

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Column.module.css";
import Xarrow, { useXarrow, Xwrapper } from "react-xarrows";

export const Column = ({ column, index }) => {
  const { name, descriptor } = column;

  const line = {
    from: "",
    to: "",
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.ColumnContainer}>
        {name}: {descriptor}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

код компонента таблиц:

```
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import React from 'react';
import Xarrow, { useXarrow, Xwrapper } from 'react-xarrows';
import { Column } from '../Column/Column';

export const DraggableBox = ({table, key, reference = undefined, id = undefined, ...style }) => {
  const {tableName, coordinates} = table;
  
  const updateXarrow = useXarrow();
  
  //if (initialOffset) moreStyle = { position: 'absolute', left: initialOffset.x, top: initialOffset.y };
  return (
    <Draggable onDrag={updateXarrow} onStop={updateXarrow}>
      <div ref={reference} id={id} style={{position: 'absolute', left: coordinates.x + 'px', top: coordinates.y + 'px', border: '2px solid'}}>
      <p>Название: {tableName}</p>
      <div>
        {table.columns.map((column, index) => (
          <Column table={table} column={column} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
      </div>
      
    </Draggable>
  );
};
введите сюда код
```

и компонент, где перебираю весь массив данных:

```
import { Table } from "../Table/Table";
import styles from "./Tables.module.css";
import tableData from "../utils/all_db_schema.json";

export const Tables = () => {
  const [tableState, setTableState] = useState(tableData);

  return (
    <>
      {tableState.map((elem, index) => (
        <div
          className={styles.AreaContainer}
          key={index}
          style={{ color: elem.color }}
        >
          <p>Имя: {elem.groupName}</p>
          <div className={styles.ClassesContainer}>
            {elem.tables.map((table, index) => (
              DraggableBox table={table} key={index} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: что именно это условие должно выполнять? и как выглядят сами точки это координаты `"x","y"` ? и еще где вы хотите использовать данные о координатах я так понимаю где-то вне `Column` тогда видимо стоит прокидывать на родительский компонент, или через `стейт менеджер` если он есть

Comment: @DaniilLoban условие должно записывать в lines откуда (от какого поля) идет стрелка и куда. Координаты нужны для размещения самих таблиц, на них у меня отдельный компонент, родительский для column

Comment: если я правильно понимаю ситуацию то стрелки идут от таблицы к таблице (от и до их колонок разумеется) но я не понимаю каким образом Вы в колонке хотите получить сразу 2 координаты, она может знать про свою только

Comment: где вы обрабатываете json? и где в нем видны связи между 2мя таблицами?

Comment: @DaniilLoban export const Tables = () => {
  const [tableState, setTableState] = useState(tableData);

  return (
    <>
      {tableState.map((elem, index) => (
        <div
          className={styles.AreaContainer}
          key={index}
          style={{ color: elem.color }}
        >
          <p>Имя: {elem.groupName}</p>
          <div className={styles.ClassesContainer}>
            {elem.tables.map((table, index) => (
              <DraggableBox table={table} key={index} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}; и в columns потом

Comment: Мария, добавьте пожалуйста это в вопрос, там под ним есть кнопочка Править

Comment: @DaniilLoban там места в ответе не хватит/ и не совсем поняла, что добавить?

Comment: извините, я имел в виду Ваш вопрос, можете кликнуть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1450547/edit) для начала его редактирования

Comment: @DaniilLoban поняла Вас, внесла изменения

Comment: Так вроде разобрался, т.е. DraggableBox выступает в качестве таблицы. Но я так и не понял из каких данных берутся координаты для стрелок. ` const line = { from: "",  to: "",  };` я бы не стал прописывать именно в `Column`, мне кажется это должно быть где-то на уровне `Tables`

Comment: @DaniilLoban согласна/ Вот именно с этим у меня и проблема: не знаю, как прописать условие, чтобы стрелка тянулась от поля с именем, равным дескриптору другого поля из другой таблицы

Comment: Ну для начала связей думаю будет много, теоретически они должны храниться в json а пока можно создать для них в `Tables` массив через `useState` например так `const [links, setLinks] = useState([])`

Comment: я попробую сейчас сделать небольшой пример кода, добавлю его в ответ, чтобы можно было дальше разбираться если что

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xarrows) **react-xarrows** сказано что в качестве `start` и `end` могут выступать строки, поэтому я предпочел их использование `useRef` (которые пришлось бы прокидывать через все приложение), достаточно чтобы это были уникальные id (по всему приложению!), я внес их в данные колонок, как `selfId`:

```
{
  name: "smthLike",
  type: "string",
  typeFormat: "",
  example: "",
  descriptor: "",
  selfId: "box1" <--- добавляем Id (уникальное среди всех)
},
```

при cоздании колонки `id` присваивается элементу:

```
export const Column = ({ column, index }) => {
  const { name, descriptor, selfId } = column;
  return (
    <div id={selfId} className={styles.ColumnContainer}> // Присваиваем id
      {name}: {descriptor}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Хранение самих ссылок можно организовывать абсолютно по-разному, поэтому эту часть я не делал, это может быть отдельный массив, что упростит парсинг для рендера или эта информация может хранится в колонке вместе с `selfId` (имена разумеется могут бы по вкусу, я назвал так чтобы не было путаницы)

В Tables выводим все имеющиеся стрелки

```
<Xarrow start="box1" end="box3" />
```

Обновляем при перетаскивании `onMouseMove={() => setUpd(!upd)}`можно обновлять любым другим способом, так как используемый здесь способ может повлиять на производительность.

Я встречал такой способ обновления, возможно у него есть свои плюсы, но все это рассчитано на плоскую структуру (когда нет вложенности компонент), т.е. текущий случай иной.

```
const [, reRender] = useReducer(() => ({}), {});
const renderCount = useRef(0);
useEffect(() => {
   renderCount.current += 1;
   if (renderCount.current === 2) {
     reRender();
     renderCount.current = 0;
   }
});
```

К сожалению `updateXarrow` в `DraggableBox` почему-то  не приводит к обновлению.

```
export const Tables = () => {
  const [upd, setUpd] = useState(false);

  return (
    .........        
    <div
       onMouseMove={() => setUpd(!upd)} // Обновляем при движении мыши
    >
     .........
      <div className={styles.ClassesContainer}>
        {elem.tables.map((table, index) => (
          <DraggableBox table={table} key={index} />
        ))}
        <Xarrow start="box1" end="box3" /> // Cтрелки
      </div>
     .........
 );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на [песочницу](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-arrows-vjw9j1) с приведенными изменениями (файлы компонент, импорт немного модифицировались!)

Comment: Тут вот какая проблема| Сейчас таблицы две| А потом их будет сотня/ Каждому полю нужно будет дать свой Id? И каждый раз отрисовывать новую стрелку
Тут нужно что-то более универсальное=< потому мне и прописали в json дескриптор

Comment: а если добавить в json свойства parent target? Можно будет реализовать такие связи по ним?

Comment: Ситуация такая что можно делать связи либо по `id` элемента либо по его `ref` (React) так как колонка является последней в цепочке а ref нужен на уровне `Tables` придется устраивать forwardRef и прокидывать до `Column` но ситуация в том что у одной таблицы может быть несколько связей и значит несколько колонок со связями но `Table`  с использованием `forwardRef` может вернуть только один `ref` иными словами `forwardRef` на это не заточен.

Comment: Поэтому я предлагаю использовать id однако Вы можете создать уникальный `id` просто -  `имя_таблицы.имя_поля` по всем правилам баз данных и то и другое будет уникально и ссумарное значение тоже т.е. в descriptor запишите `Two.codePlatform` и таким образом задача будет решена так же как в ответе и не нужно будет ломать голову с уникальностью

Comment: Мария, если будут сложности с тем что я описал, обращайтесь подправлю ответ под то что тут написано

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное) Будем обсуждать с нашими бэк-разрабами) Чтобы правильный json создать под такое) А то таблиц и полей будут сотни...

Comment: думаю что добавить имя таблицы к дескриптору не самый плохой вариант, в реальных бд так же участвует имя таблицы (поля могут совпадать в разных таблицах)